# how to add html in dynamically created div

Tags: javascript, html

I create a div from a DB with the below code

```
<div id="' + row.flatno + '"></div>
```

How can I select this div in order to add html code?? I use this

```
$('input').keyup(function(){
    $(this).html("SomeText: <strong>" + diff + "</strong>");
});
```

but nothing happens

Comment: Well, in that context `this` is the `input` node, not the `div`. Use a selector.

Comment: can you please advise the syntax?

Comment: The given answer is correct. However, if you do not have access to that `row.flatno` in that piece of code, you can always add a class to the div when you create it, say `<div class="mydiv"...`, and select it using `$('.mydiv').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As  @xzoert mentioned with `this` you refer to input.

```
$('input').keyup(function(){
    $('#'+row.flatno).html("SomeText: <strong>" + diff + "</strong>");
});
```

The part 
    `$('#'+row.flatno)`should query id that you are looking for.